# Google Cloud Platform DNS: unable to set domain name without www to point to server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dns

I am new to GCP. I have configured a computing engine and am trying to set the DNS entries. I have updated the Name Servers on the Registrar DNS settings. On the GCP DNS configuration I have set

(a) the A record
(b) the CNAME records

when I access the site using `https://www.hida.app` it works but when I try with `https://hida.app` it does not.

I also notice that when I ping with `www.hida.app` it pings showing the static IP address in GCP, but when I ping with just `hida.app` it shows some other address

Here is the screen shot

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If `hida.app` pointed somewhere else (to another IP address), then after changing the resource record entry, you will have to wait for the TTL to expire. For your `hida.app` resource record, this is 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes @JohnHanley. Now it seems to be working. Just to mention, I did try it after an hour yesterday but it did not seem to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TTL (Time To Live) is the expiration time (valid till this time period) for a DNS record. With the TTL value, the DNS serves, inform the recursive server or local resolver how long it should keep this DNS record in its cache. The longer the TTL, the longer the resolver holds that information in its cache. The shorter the TTL, the shorter amount of time the resolver holds that information in its cache.

In your case, you have done the test within the specified TTL time and while the recursive server or local resolver was answering from the cache. Which [@John Hanley](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) described in his comment.

Comment: I believe this behavior is well explained in [this Serverfault thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/774388/i-changed-my-ttl-from-24-hours-to-5-minutes-do-i-need-to-wait-24-hours-before-c)